# relationship between different Objects in Java

Tags: java-8

I have a list `final List<Integer> met= employee.getNumbers();`

```
if(employeee.isNew()){
   mets.clear();
   for (int met= 0; met< employee.getNumbers().size() / 3; met++) {
        mets.add(met);
    }
    employee.setNumbers(mets);
}
```

Now when I clear `mets` the `employee numbers` also gets cleared. Can Someone elaborate me this behavior from java .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone explain me this Java behavior?

The actual behavior depends on how the `getNumbers()` method has been implemented:

- It could return the list instance that that the `Employee` class uses to hold the numbers.  If it is doing that, then `met.clear()` is going to clear *that* list, and that is going to affect the state of the `Employee`.
- It could create and return a *shallow copy* of the list.  If it does that, then `met.clear()` won't affect the `Employee` state.

Based on what you are saying, it seems that your `Employee.getNumbers` method is returning the list rather than a copy of the list.

You *could* change that.  You could return a copy of the list.  You could return a read-only wrapper for the list created using `Collections.unmodifiableList`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from your definition of met, you link it to the employee.getNumbers(), it's the same list. You need to do like you do do after :

```
final List<Integer> met= new ArrayList<>();
for(Integer i:employee.getNumbers()) {
    met.add(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You working with Objects, hence when you say `List<Integer> met = employee.getNumbers()` your ***not*** actually creating an independent copy of the list being returned from `employee.getNumbers()`.

Instead, the list being referenced by `met` points to the same location in memory as where the list being returned from `employee.getNumbers()` resides. Hence any changes to `met` will be applied to the list begin returned from `employee.getNumbers()`, because they are actually one and the same (they share the same location in memory).

Comment: That's it, really well explained.